# Send keystrokes to other applications

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a program in C# that lets me send a keystroke to another program that's open but is not in the foreground. The purpose of the program is to let me start recording gameplay footage from my Xbox 360 using TotalMedia Extreme while also starting recording in audacity to record from the PC mic. That way I can get both tracks to be synced instead of starting gameplay recording and quickly switching to audacity and clicking record.

Basically all I need this program to do is detect a mouse click while TotalMedia Extreme is in the foreground and when the mouse is clicked, send the hotkey command to Audacity to start recording. Does anyone have an idea for how I could get started with this?

This seems like it might be a good place to start, but I don't think it will do the same thing I need to do:

[Send fast textinput to another process (Window)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542226/send-fast-textinput-to-another-process-window)

Answer (score 1):

Check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632589(v=vs.85).aspx
I suppose you could do it through Windows Hooks, in particular WH_KEYBOARD_LL

Answer (score 0):

Just use [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). The command [SendMessage](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/PostMessage.htm) will send keystrokes to a non-active window, but you could also just have AHK activate the right window before sending keystrokes. Once you are done you can wrap it into a handy little hotkey or even compile it into an `exe` file.

Answer (score 0):

AutoHotKey is definitely the rout I'd go. You can use a function called [ControlSend](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlSend.htm) to send keystrokes to specific controls of specific applications, even if they're in the background. Sounds like it would work perfectly for what you're needing. The forums over at AHKScript.org are really helpful too, so you might check them out as well!